# Generate multiple random sentences instead of one using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, random, sentence

Hi friends am trying to generate multiple random sentences instead of 1.Here is my code..

```
<div id="content" >
    <?php 
    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2');
    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }


    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['facts'].'&nbsp';
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

My database table name is questions and my column name is facts.Here is my pattern

```
  facts
  ramu
  somesh
  kumar
  getup
```

Right now am getting output as

```
    ramu getup
```

How can I get multiple sentences when page is refreshed only once like below without duplicate sentences

```
      ramu getup
     somesh ramu
     kumar somesh
```

Thanks

Comment: remove `LIMIT 2` from your query

Comment: if i remove 2 i will get combination of all words at a time i want combination of only two words as multiple sentences

Comment: how about *printing a line break after every second word*? or: *looping over the whole code*?

Comment: if i print with br then I will get ramu and getup in different lines not as sentence in same line

Answer (score 0):

Remove LIMIT 2 to get all rows in any order.
You'll get an array of rows.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $rows[] = $row['facts'];
}
```

Count the length of the array.

```
$rowsCount = count($rows)
```

Access the array in a loop depending how many sentences you need like this:

```
echo $rows[rand(0, $rowsCount)] . ' ' . $rows[rand(0, $rowsCount)] . '<br />';
```